# Large binary read in windows 10 is faster when run as admin

Tags: c++, windows, performance, admin, binaryfiles

I have an application that reads large binary files and all is well, but it runs much faster as admin than via my normal account.  Can someone please help me understand why?

The sample application below exhibits the issue.  Some specifics:
Windows 10.0.19041
C++11 built in Visual Studio 2019 (as x64).
Stand alone machine, no domain, just a normal user account with admin privileges, and
the test file is local.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto aFile = R"(SomeLargeBinaryFile)";
    std::ifstream fileStream(aFile, std::ios::binary);
    
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock TheClock;
    auto startTime = TheClock::now();

    int offset = (int)2e8;
    fileStream.seekg(offset);
    
    int bucketSize = (int)3.75e8;
    double* bucket = new double[bucketSize]();

    fileStream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bucket), sizeof(double) * bucketSize);

    auto endTime = TheClock::now();
    auto elapsed = endTime - startTime;
    auto elapsedMS = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(elapsed);
    auto elapsedSec = elapsedMS.count() / 1000.0;

    std::cout << " Sample reader elapsed seconds: " << elapsedSec << std::endl;

    fileStream.close();
    delete[] bucket;
}
```

Comment: probably your antivirus scanner or caching effects

Comment: How can we answer if we don't have access to your machine?

Comment: Do they both produce the same end results?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie We send ninjas to steal the computer. Duh.

Comment: Maybe you ran the second time as admin and it was cached.

Comment: @OP There is nothing in that code that suggests where the issue is.  It is basically generic C++ file I/O code.  That's why without access to your computer, all you'll get are guesses.

Comment: Time to fire up `xperf` to figure out where the extra time is going.  Take a profile of the machine when running as admin, and then when run as normal user.  My guess is you are going to see AV scanner or some other process causing the issue.  Side note: make sure AV is enabled on your admin account!!!

Comment: Of course, I'd be interested in seeing if anyone else has the issue.  Thanks for the AV suggestions... sound good and I'll check into them.  And yes.  The same build of the exe produces the same results either way.

Comment: As file streams always travel via the `std::codecvt` facet of the installed `std::locale` I could imagine that the user has a "fancy" locale setting while the admin has none and the default "C" `std::locale` is used. That `std::locale` has the interesting property that it's `std::codecvt` returns `true` from `always_noconv()` and the processing may be optimized. You can verify or debunk that theory easily by using `std::locale::global(std::locale::classic());` before creating the file stream. (... and while you are at it, you may want to also try `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);`).